# An issue that use Emerge to install package

Tags: gentoo, emerge

I'm not too much experienced within Gentoo portage, When I tried to install Nodejs 
    `# emerge --ask monit nginx nodejs` 
into my gentoo and i get an error message like:

```
[ebuild  N     ] net-libs/http-parser-2.6.1  USE="-static-libs" ABI_X86="(64) -32 (-x32)" 
[ebuild   R    ] dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2f  USE="-bindist*" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-libs/libuv-1.8.0  USE="-static-libs" ABI_X86="(64) -32 (-x32)" 
[ebuild  N     ] app-admin/monit-5.16.1  USE="pam ssl -libressl" 
[ebuild  N     ] www-servers/nginx-1.9.10-r3  USE="http http-cache http2 ipv6 pcre ssl -aio -debug -libatomic -libressl -luajit -pcre-jit -rtmp (-selinux) -threads -vim-syntax" NGINX_MODULES_HTTP="access auth_basic autoindex browser charset empty_gif fastcgi geo gzip limit_conn limit_req map memcached proxy referer rewrite scgi split_clients ssi upstream_ip_hash userid uwsgi -addition -ajp -auth_ldap -auth_pam -auth_request -cache_purge -dav -dav_ext -degradation -echo -fancyindex -flv -geoip -gunzip -gzip_static -headers_more -image_filter -lua -memc -metrics -mogilefs -mp4 -naxsi -perl -push_stream -random_index -realip -secure_link -security -slice -slowfs_cache -spdy -sticky -stub_status -sub -upload_progress -upstream_check -xslt" NGINX_MODULES_MAIL="-imap -pop3 -smtp" NGINX_MODULES_STREAM="-access -limit_conn -upstream"                                         
[ebuild  N     ] net-libs/nodejs-5.6.0-r1  USE="npm snapshot ssl -debug -doc -icu {-test}" CPU_FLAGS_X86="sse2" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7"                    

!!! Multiple package instances within a single package slot have been pulled
!!! into the dependency graph, resulting in a slot conflict:

dev-libs/openssl:0

  (dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2f:0/0::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) pulled in by
>=dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2f:0=[-bindist] required by (net-libs/nodejs-5.6.0-r1:0/0::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge)
                             ^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                    

  (dev-libs/openssl-1.0.2f:0/0::gentoo, installed) pulled in by
>=dev-libs/openssl-0.9.8f:0[bindist=] required by (net-misc/openssh-7.1_p2-r1:0/0::gentoo, installed)
                            ^^^^^^^^                                                                                                     
dev-libs/openssl:0[bindist=] required by (dev-qt/qtnetwork-5.5.1:5/5::gentoo, installed)
                   ^^^^^^^^                                                                                                 


It may be possible to solve this problem by using package.mask to
prevent one of those packages from being selected. However, it is also
possible that conflicting dependencies exist such that they are
impossible to satisfy simultaneously.  If such a conflict exists in
the dependencies of two different packages, then those packages can
not be installed simultaneously. You may want to try a larger value of
the --backtrack option, such as --backtrack=30, in order to see if
that will solve this conflict automatically.

For more information, see MASKED PACKAGES section in the emerge man
page or refer to the Gentoo Handbook.
```

After that, I try `emerge --sync` and `emerge -u world` but not fine.
Some topic said I should remove `ssl` but I'm not sure it's a real way to solve it.

Comment: post `emerge --info`.

Answer (score 2):

I reinstall the `openssh` `openssl` `qtnetwork` without '`bindist`' flag as https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1020062-highlight-nodejs.html said, 
and the problem solved! All packages were successfully rebuilded.